# Microsoft outlook doesn't shows German umlauts

Tags: utf-8, outlook, jakarta-mail, spring-framework-beans

I have an email send through SMTP which contains some German characters (umlauts). The encoding used is 'UTF-8', but the content is not displaying correctly.

But when I choose the 'view source' in outlook app (by right click), the result shows all the umlauts. See in high lighted.
[image]

How to solve this problem? The content of the mail is created programmatically through the following code.

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, false, "utf-8");
mimeMessage.setContent("<html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"></head><body>Hallo Saju Paul,<p>Wir.....", "text/html");

helper.setTo("sender@sender.com");
helper.setSubject("Setze dein Passwort zurück");
helper.setFrom("undefined@variables.env");
mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

where mailSender is

```
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question does not allow us to tell for sure, but the usual explanation is that the actual character set isn't UTF-8. Probable character set candidates include Latin-1 and UTF-16. To ask a well-defined question, please provide an unambiguous representation of the bytes in the problematic textual data; see also the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info)

Comment: Anyway, if your message is HTML, a portable ASCII-only representation is available by way of entity codes; for example, `ü` is `&uuml;`

Comment: The corruption in *läuft* looks like UTF-16 or perhaps UCS-2 mojibake.